# Java inheritance and Activities

Tags: java, android, inheritance

i have class A which configures itself parsing a xml file.
  Class B extends A and configures itself parsing a xml file that has more tags then the previous.

```
class A {
  protected String mFoo;

  protected loadFromXml (...){
     ...
     mFoo = ...
     ...
  }
}

class B extends A {
    protected String mBar;

    protected loadFromXml (...){
    super.loadFromXml(...);

    ...
    mBar = ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Now, I have ActivityA which configures itself through class A:

```
class ActivityA extends Activity {

protected A mAInstance;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mAInstance.loadFromXml(...);
    ...
    other code...
        ...
    }
}
```

and ActivityB:

```
class ActivityB extends ActivityA{

   protected B mBInstance;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    mBInstance.loadFromXml(...);
...
   }
}
```

Now, the problem is: ActivityB holds mAInstance and mBInstance, which share a subset of the same data (mFoo). How to load only mBInstance? I need of course to call the super in onCreate in ActivityB...

Comment: Original post edited, it was missing an extends...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assume ActivityB extends ActivityA, otherwise A is not accessible from ActivityB.

Then, you could remove the mBInstance from B since you have already a type of A already available.
When you load the xml, move the call to loadFromXML to a new method like:

In ActivityA:

```
protected onCreate(...) {
 ....
 loadXML();
}

protected void loadXML() {
  getNewInstance().loadFromXML();
}

protected A getNewInstance() {
  return new A();
}
```

Then in ActivityB you need to override onlye the getNewInstance() to:

```
protected A getNewInstance() {
 return new B();
}
```

Remove also `mBInstance.loadFromXml(...);` from `ActivityB#onCreate(...)`
polymorphism to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

I would use polymorphism and move the `loadFromXml()` call to a protected method, as suggested by gunar. You also need to solve how to access the instance of `A` or `B` with correct types, though. Here is an example:

Classes `A` and `B`:

```
class A {
   public String mFoo;
   protected void loadFromXml() {}
}

class B extends A {
    public String mBar;

    @Override
    protected void loadFromXml() {}
 }
```

Class `ActivityA`

```
class ActivityA {
    private A mAInstance; // do not access this directly, use getter

    protected A getMInstance() { // getter
        return mAInstance;
    }

    @override
    public void onCreate() {
        initMInstance();
    }

    protected void initMInstance() {
        mAInstance = new A();
        mAInstance.loadFromXml();
    }

    private void f() {
        String s = getMInstance().mFoo; // access mAInstance like this
    }
}
```

Class `ActivityB`

```
class ActivityB extends ActivityA {
    private B mBInstance;

    @Override
    protected B getMInstance() { // override getter, ActivityA will see type A, activityB type B
        return mBInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        initMInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void initMInstance() {
        mBInstance = new B();
        mBInstance.loadFromXml();
    }

    private void f() {
        String s1 = getMInstance().mFoo; // here you can access both properties
        String s2 = getMInstance().mBar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When in `B.loadFromXml()` you do

```
super.loadFromXml(...);
```

You will not affect the mAinstance at all. Since it is not static, I assume you are updating the `this` attributes in it and not creating any new instance; you will be updating the `B` instance even if it is the code in the `A` class.

Comment: Ok, there is a problem of duplicated data in memory, because mAInstance and mBInstance holds the duplicated mFoo (in real life, much more fields and data)... I want to avoid this situation, and load ONLY mBInstance in ActivityB

Comment: But `mFoo` is part of `B` too. Attributes get extended along the classes.